# Galaxy S3 Bug: No text appears when typing SMS message

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, bugs

Summary: When starting to write an SMS text message using the stock Messaging app, no text appears.

Reproduction: It's intermittent. However IIRC it has only happened when replying.

Workarounds:

1. reboot phone (Always works)
2. press back repeatedly to exit message app. (Works half the time)
3. switch app and then back (works only sometimes)
4. keep typing rubbish until something appears (often works but typically only after a couple of hundred characters).

Are there any fixes for this?

Comment: Are you using the stock Messaging app, or a 3rd-party app?

Comment: The one that comes with it. (I don't know if Samsung butcher the Android one though)

Comment: What keyboard are you using? Does this happen in other apps like hangout etc?

Comment: I'm using the keyboard which came with the phone when new. (How would I find out which one that is?) I have not had the problem with any other apps except, coincidentally, just one other one recently: a text box within a 3rd party app I downloaded. But only the once.